# In App Subscription Upgrade/Downgrade Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Trying to use the new intent for upgrading/downgrading subscriptions `getBuyIntentExtraParams`

Here is my line invoking it:

```
mService.getBuyIntentExtraParams(7, getPackageName(), iapSku, "subs", DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD, extras);
```

The problem is that when I open the popup for the payment flow as provided by Google Play, I receive the error:

```
We are unable to change your subscription plan. Manage subscriptions.
```

Previously I was using `getBuyIntent` and the process worked well.

I am uncertain what the error means or where to even begin debugging it. I've looked around to see what this means but had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: I have ended up using getBuyIntentToReplaceSkus which has a similar functionality

Comment: Did you solve it somehow? I'm forced into when trying to use new Google Library: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html and upgrade/downgrade subscription :/. when set `builder.setOldSkus(...)`